# Restricting Google Shopping API by

Tags: php, google-api, google-shopping-api

I am trying to use the Google Shopping API (for PHP) to query certain products and return the price for only a selection of stores - e.g. Amazon, HMV and was wondering how to restrict the results to certain stores?

Can't find the answer in the API documentation or online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/reference-request-parameters), the accountId property is the *Id of the merchant center account that published the product*. That sounds an awful lot like the store.

Create an array of merchant id numbers you would like to have, for example:

```
$merchants = array('Amazon' => '123456',
                   'HMV' => '789012');
```

Then generate your request and pass those values as the accountId. I'm not sure if you can pass multiple values at a time.

One thing to note, is it may be difficult to find the accountId of some merchants. See this: https://groups.google.com/group/google-content-api-for-shopping/browse_thread/thread/e0c4d098e25f97c8